# how to display a textlabel as well as draw a circle on clicking a pushbutton "ADD"

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5, qpainter, qt-signals, qtwidgets

I have read all related article of multiple slots with one signal but I am unable to display at the time of drawing a circle both trigerred by a push button "ADD". I can display the text label near the circle before clicking the button but i want it to dislay only after clicking the button. Please Help. Also, i want the text label to be near circle and can be modified anytime on clicking

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow,QPushButton,QWidget
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRect,Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter,QBrush, QPen
from PyQt5 import QtCore


class Window(QMainWindow):
   def __init__(self):
        super(Window,self).__init__()
        title="layout management"
        left=500
        top=200
        width=500
        height=400
        iconName="fosseeicon.jpg"
        self.setWindowTitle(title)
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon(iconName))
        self.setGeometry(left, top, width, height)
        self.should_paint_circle = False
        self.windowcomponents()
        self.initUI()
        self.show()
   def initUI(self):
       if self.should_paint_circle:
           self.label=QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
           self.label.setText('<h2>circle<h2>')
   def windowcomponents(self):
       button=QPushButton("Add", self)
       button.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 50, 28))
       button.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon("addbutton.png"))
       button.setToolTip("<h3>This is for creating random circles<h3>")
       button.clicked.connect(self.paintcircle)
       button=QPushButton("Generate Report", self)
       button.setGeometry(QRect(49,0,150,28))
       button.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon("generatereport.png"))
       button.setToolTip("This is for generating pdf report of connection between two circles")
       button=QPushButton("Save", self)
       button.setGeometry(QRect(199,0,120,28))
       button.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon("saveicon.png"))
       button.setToolTip("This is for saving an image of canvas area")

   def paintEvent(self, event):
       super().paintEvent(event)
       if self.should_paint_circle:
           painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
           painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
           painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.black, 5, Qt.SolidLine))
           painter.drawEllipse(100, 100, 100, 100)
           self.initUI()
           self.label.move(60,100)
   def paintcircle(self, painter):
       self.should_paint_circle = True
       self.update()
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
circle=Window()
circle.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Explain this sentence: *can be modified anytime on clicking*

Comment: that means user can modify the text label on clicking

Comment: i.e. user can change the text label whenever it clicks it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Widgets that are created with a parent, outside their `__init__` (or their parent's), but *not* added to a layout, have to be explicitly shown; you're missing this:

```
    self.label.show()
```

Besides that, you **MUST NOT** create new widgets within the paintEvent.

Painting is something that happens often, usually in the following situations (which happen *very often*:

- when the widget is shown the first time
- whenever the widget is hidden and shown again (for example, after minimizing and restoring the window)
- whenever the mouse enters or exits it and/or its children
- when the widget or any of its parents are resized
- **when a new children is shown**

The result is that if you add a widget for each paint event, you'll probably end up with dozens (if not hundreds or thousands) of widgets, and, most importantly if you also show it, it will cause an infinite recursion.

```
class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window,self).__init__()
        title="layout management"
        left=500
        top=200
        width=500
        height=400
        iconName="fosseeicon.jpg"
        self.setWindowTitle(title)
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon(iconName))
        self.setGeometry(left, top, width, height)
        self.should_paint_circle = False
        self.windowcomponents()
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.label.hide()

    # ...

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        super().paintEvent(event)
        if self.should_paint_circle:
            painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
            painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
            painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.black, 5, Qt.SolidLine))
            painter.drawEllipse(100, 100, 100, 100)

    def paintcircle(self, painter):
        self.should_paint_circle = True
        self.label.setText('<h2>circle<h2>')
        self.label.move(60,100)
        self.label.show()
        self.update()
```

That said, based on this question and the previous one, I suggest you to study the documentation more carefully, especially what is related to the [QMainWindow](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html), the [Layout management](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html), [painting in Qt](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/paintsystem-drawing.html) and the related [QPainter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html) documentation.

Comment: please suggest how to read the documentation, from where to start because i am new to pyqt5 and i have learnt basics through python programming on youtube videos. Moreover, some of the links that you have given above shows code in c++

Comment: please reply soon

Comment: The documentation is for C++, but the functions and parameters are the same in Python for 99% of the classes and their functions: in the pages related to classes, for each function there is the returned value on the left ("void" means that it returns None in Python), on the right the function name and its parameters. In case of doubt regarding parameters and return values, use `help(class.function)` in the python shell or read the [PyQt docs](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/). Besides that, all the logics behind each class applies to Python as it does with C++.